# Reducing coordinate precision in MSSQL WKT using C#?

Tags: c#, geometry, well-known-text, sql-server-spatial

When you use the AsText() function on geometry objects in MSSQL Server 2008+ you get something like this:

```
"LINESTRING (8.8446177236171337 47.721989356913951, 8.844617919281065 47.721977134398223, 8.844589303417802 47.721976942728766, 8.84454742773029 47.7219801783058, 8.8445167302356325 47.721989634438941, ...)"
```

The precision of the coordinates is far to great to be useful (for me). For wgs84 coordinates the seventh decimal place is worth ~11 mm. After that, it gets more or less meaningless.

For my workflow I need to put a lot of WKT's in a Textfile. To reduce file size I would like to reduce the coordinate precision to six decimal places.

I could process the textfile and reduce precision in my backend (c#, entity framework) but that seems like a rather costly task.

Is there a way in MSSQL Server to create WKT from geometry objects with a defined number of decimal places?